# $\mathbb{C}P^2$ is not diffeomorphic to $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

I am working through *4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus* by Stipsicz and Gompf. At the beginning of Section 1.3, they have a list of exercises regarding $\mathbb{C}P^n$ and $\mathbb{R}P^n$. The part I couldn't figure out is as follows:

> Prove that there is no orientation-preserving diffeomorphism between $\mathbb{C}P^2$ and $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$.

Here $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$ denotes $\mathbb{C}P^2$ with the opposite orientation. This question is asked right after showing that the intersection form of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ is $\langle 1 \rangle$ while the intersection form of $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$ is $\langle -1 \rangle$. I am assuming I somehow need to make use of this fact. [Here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/cp-2-and-cp-2-bar-are-not-diffeomorphic.397132/) is an answer from another blog, but I couldn't really understand how it works.

Comment: The first argument there is that a diffeo of CP2 cannot reverse the orientation.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Well I am looking for a map from $\mathbb{C}P^2$ to $\mathbb{C}P^2$ with opposite orientation. So that argument should work here, isn't that true?

Comment: The first answer there is straightforward; what are you confused about in it? The bit about intersection forms is just unravelling its definition in terms of the cohomology ring $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^2; \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}[x_2]/(x_2^3)$.

Comment: @anomaly I think I was confused about the way f interacted with the cohomology ring. Could you take a look at my answer below and see if I did anything wrong?

Comment: @CeyhunElmacioglu: Looks fine, although I would just say that $[\mathbb{CP^2}] = a^2$ and $[\overline{\mathbb{CP^2}}] = -a^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think I have an answer now. We know that if $a\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is a generator, then $a^2 = a\smile a\in H^4(\mathbb{C}P^2)$ is simply $[\mathbb{C}P^2]$. Consequently, $-a^2 = -a\smile a = [\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}]$.  Suppose we have a map $f:\mathbb{C}P^2\xrightarrow{} \mathbb{C}P^2$. Then $f_\ast(a) = ca$ for some $c\in \mathbb{Z}$, which in turn implies
$$f_\ast(a\smile a) = f_\ast(a)\smile f_\ast(a) = ca\smile ca = c^2 (a\smile a) $$
Since $c^2 \neq -1$, there is no map $f$ that reverses the orientation.